# Convert a string in code in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to convert a string in code in Java, but i have no idea how to do it or if it is possible.

This is my Java code (Measure is an other class I have created)

```
String str= "Measure m = new Measure(10,1);";
```

Is it possible to run the code in the string?

Comment: what are trying to do ?

Comment: Whatever you write inside a String, will be considered as a value by JVM.

Comment: @ArifMustafa Ok thank you!

Comment: @Ravi it's clear, OP want to have user dependent value to be used as code at runtime. While that could be dangerous in some way that could, in the same time, be useful.

Answer (score 0):

No I dont think that is a good practice, you don't need to do it that way, 
just instantiate outside of the string, it will be fine and good practice.
Measure m = new Measure(10,1);

Comment: And what if the String is variable or even user dependent? There are lots of cases in which you need to execute code that is passed as a String. And there *are* ways to do that (see comments under the question).